# In python, how to add command to bash_profile?

Tags: python, bash, google-colaboratory

My enviroment is Google Colab, which is in Python. I am trying to follow the instructions on this website.

https://github.com/abisee/cnn-dailymail

And it mentions to

> Then add the following command to your bash_profile:

```
export CLASSPATH=/path/to/stanford-corenlp-full-2017-06-09/stanford-corenlp-3.8.0.jar
```

My best guess was to run using

!export CLASSPATH=/stanford-corenlp-full-2017-06-09/stanford-corenlp-3.8.0.jar

Which executed without any errors

But then the instructions say to

> You can check if it's working by running

```
echo "Please tokenize this text." | java edu.stanford.nlp.process.PTBTokenizer
```

So I tried

```
!echo "Please tokenize this text." | java edu.stanford.nlp.process.PTBTokenizer
```

But then I got this error

```
Error: Could not find or load main class edu.stanford.nlp.process.PTBTokenizer
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: edu.stanford.nlp.process.PTBTokenizer
```

Edit:

I found instructions to install Java in colab

```
# Install Java
!apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jdk-headless -qq > /dev/null
os.environ["JAVA_HOME"] = "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64"
!java -version
```

But

```
!echo "Please tokenize this text." | java edu.stanford.nlp.process.PTBTokenizer
```

Still gives the same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend *not* changing your `.bash_profile` as you're going to accumulate settings and junk.

Instead, java lets you specify CLASSPATH with the `-cp` option, which we can add to the Python script.

(You can also use `java -cp /path/to/blahblah.jar etc` to test it as their instructions recommend.)

Change this line [in make_datafile.py](https://github.com/abisee/cnn-dailymail/blob/master/make_datafiles.py#L76) to:

```
command = ['java', '-cp', '/path/to/blahblah.jar', 'edu.stanford.nlp.process.PTBTokenizer', 
           '-ioFileList', '-preserveLines', 'mapping.txt']
```

If you're still having trouble, make sure you have a valid jar!

List the contents with:

```
jar -tvf /path/to/blahblah.jar
```

You should see `edu/stanford/nlp/process/PTBTokenizer.class` listed, otherwise no amount of messing with the CLASSPATH will fix it.

Comment: Brilliant solution! I was also able to confirm it's working by running `!echo "Please tokenize this text." | java -cp stanford-corenlp-full-2018-10-05/stanford-corenlp-3.9.2.jar edu.stanford.nlp.process.PTBTokenizer`